# ggplot2 with colour blind ggthemes except black

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a general line of code I can apply to any `ggplot` grouped barchart I make. I want it to make my graphs colour blind friendly. In the library `ggthemes`, the `scale_fill_colorblind`  function does just the job. My problem is that  black is often picked as one of the colours; I sometimes need to overlay confidence intervals and other stuff, so black is not really an option.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar(position="dodge")+
scale_fill_colorblind()
```

Is there any way to to have within the `scale_fill_colourblind` some code that tells it not to pick black? I don't want to list the colours manually because I want it to be compatible with lots of different data (some may have two "fills", some 10 etc...).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems like something the package author might consider adding. I am not a color expert, but it seems like using black for one group , orange for another, and blue for another implies that the data in black are the default, which is often not what we want colors to communicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at best a hack,

```
ggthemes_data$colorblind  <- ggthemes_data$colorblind[-1]
assignInNamespace("ggthemes_data", ggthemes_data, ns="ggthemes")

last_plot() + scale_fill_colorblind()
```

Comment: What would you do to revert this hack?

Comment: I'd probably restart R, or maybe try detach() the package and reload it

Answer (score 3):

This answer builds on the answer from Alec but creates a function that returns `scale_fill_discrete` with a type argument equal to a vector of the last 7 colors used by `scale_fill_colorblind`. You do not have to specify the number of groups in your data; if there are N groups, `scale_fill_discrete` will use the first N colors in its `type` argument. The function I wrote will also let you select which colors you want, so you can drop black or use the 2nd, 4th, and 5th colors.

## Load packages

```
library(ggplot2)
# Included because this is what I used to make the images:
theme_set(theme_minimal()) 
library(ggthemes)
```

## Define color/fill functions

```
# Fill
scale_fill_colorblind7 = function(.ColorList = 2L:8L, ...){
    scale_fill_discrete(..., type = colorblind_pal()(8)[.ColorList])
}

# Color
scale_color_colorblind7 = function(.ColorList = 2L:8L, ...){
    scale_color_discrete(..., type = colorblind_pal()(8)[.ColorList])
}
```

The default value of `.ColorList` is `2:8` because there are 8 colors in the colorblind palette, and the first is black (the one we want to drop).

## Usage

Use the functions like any other `scale` function:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_colorblind7()
```

[image: Histogram of diamond clarity by cut]

You can also specify breaks as part of the `...` argument.They get passed through to `...` in `scale_fill_discrete`.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_colorblind7(breaks = diamonds$cut)
```

[image: Histogram of diamond clarity by cut]

Don't like those colors? Tell the function which colors to use (their positions):

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_colorblind7(.ColorList = c(3,4,7,6,1))
```

[image: Histogram of diamond clarity by cut]

Answer (score 2):

Another option is use `scale_fill_manual` with `ggthemes::colorblind_pal`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_colorblind()


n <- length(unique(diamonds$cut))

# or 
n <- data.table::uniqueN(diamonds$cut)

# Manually fill the geom with breaks provided by the data
#  and getting one extra color from ggthemes::colorblind_pal
#  then dropping black (the first color)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = diamonds$cut, 
                    values = colorblind_pal()(n + 1)[-1])
```